# How to reference the string of a function name in R?

Tags: r, string, function

```
hello = function(day){
    print day 
    print "was a good day"
}

func = hello
func("Monday")


print(func) #Want it to print "hello"
```

I am trying to have `print(func)` print the literal string "hello" yet still have `func("Monday")` work in other parts of my code. Is it possible to do this? How can I specify func as the literal "hello"?

I have tried

```
as.character(func)
deparse (func)
```

but to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: None of the code above runs at all. Try `hello = function(x) sprintf("%s was a good day",x); func = function(x) hello(x); body(func)[[1]]`. That's as close as you'll get, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
as.character(quote(hello))
```

But func is not associated with the name hello anymore. The contents of the hello function get transferred over but not the name hello. So you can't use func to recover the hello string.

Edit: actually I was wrong. See Frank's comment. You could do something like this:

```
hello = function(x) sprintf("%s was a good day",x)

func = function(x) hello(x); 

as.character(body(func)[[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `func <- hello`, you want `func <- "hello"`

Comment: Miswrote the question, I would still want to have ` func("Monday") ` work in my code. It seems like my implementation may not work directly. Is there a workaround I can use?

Comment: I'm confused.  You named the function `hello`, but you are calling it with `func()`.  Why?